# Can I play Minecraft without logging in first?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I have Minecraft a long time, but i deleted all my files, and installed them back, now i moved and im stuck with no connection, (except my laptop but its hard to play on here) so, i wanted to play minecraft, and i havent played after uninstallment and now it asks me to log on but i cant, i thought it would show me the menu and say Play Offline but it wont, minecraft launcher is 1.6.11, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you need to at-least log in once to prove that you bought the game.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll get to my other home, put connection to it. And ill logon.

Comment: I use a USB loader and load my games from my SDcard (using USB app loader). That way I take my game with me everywhere I go. And most computers allow you to run it, even very secure computers :) If you can open your sdcard or usb drive then you can run it typically. I store all my Steam games this way too (except from an external harddrive) Lets me play games on any computer and doesn't leave any traces or paper trial.

Comment: @ydobonebi That's actually a really cool idea, thanks for the tip man!

Comment: @Alagaros NP, I use Ceedo, which costs, but there are free versions, and since MC is java and has its own loader, I think you can do it as is.